# Calculate total score in SQL query from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables for a competition:

### User:

- Id
- Name
- Email
- EntryId

### Entry:

- Id
- Age
- Gender
- State

### GameResult:

- Id
- EntryId
- Duration
- Score

### QuestionResult:

- Id
- EntryId
- Correct
- UsersAnswer

Each entry will have multiple games, and multiple questions. I need to perform a query that will find a list of the highest scores, and then also break down highest score by demographic, i.e. Age, Gender, State.

The calculations are as follows:

Each correct question will have a score value assigned, e.g. 10 points for each correct answer. Each game will have the score already defined in its column.

So, for an entry, the total score will be:

(Count(Qn.Correct) * QuestionScore) + SUM(G1.Score, G2.Score, Gn.Score)

Not sure where to start in figuring this query out.

Comment: Does the user and entry have a 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: Yes, user can only have one entry, and entry belongs to one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note sure individual answer score would be relevant here since you already have final score on the GameResult table.

```
select e.Age, max(gr.Score) as Score
from Entry e
inner join GameResult gr on(gr.EntryID=e.EntryID)
group by e.Age
```

then repeat the same thing for the gender and state.

edit: ok, I am not sure I am following your high level design here, but whatever...
You need to group your results by the entry ID first, and then by Age/Gender/State. An extra complexity level, but otherwise exactly the same task.

```
with GameResultScore as (
select EntryID, sum(Score) as Score
from GameResult
group by EntryID
),
QuestionResultScore as (
select EntryID, count(*) CorrectAnswers
from QuestionResult
where Correct=1
group by EntryID
)

select e.Age, max(isnull(grs.Score,0)+isnull(qrs.CorrectAnswers,0) * QuestionScore) as Score
from Entry e
left join GameResultScore  grs on(grs.EntryID=e.EntryID)
left join QuestionResultScore qrs on(qrs.EntryID=e.EntryID)
group by e.Age
```

Comment: Your query is only getting the max score from the GameResult table, but each entry has multiple GameResult rows, so the sum of these has to be found. The total GameResult, then has to be added to how many Questions were answered correctly, multiplied by a static score, e.g. 20, so if the person played 4 games, and each game score was 10, and they answered 4 questions correctly, their total score would be (40 + 80) = 120

Comment: Its not much different, but that should what you want... If not, you sould be able to polish it yourself. You might wanna read up on `group by`.